# GitHub repo with submodules and devtools install R packages

Tags: r, github, git-submodules, devtools

Consider the following example:

I have a reposity `repo` that contains my R package directory `repo/pkg` and a submodule `repo/submodule`. Note that `submodule` is at the same level as package directory. I don't need all files from `submodule` in my package but instead, I need a subset of it that I need copied to `repo/pkg/src` before installation.

I also have a `repo/setup` script that copies the necessary files from `submodule` to `pkg/src`.

My end goal is to allow user to install my package using `devtools::install_git()` or similar command.
Is there a devtools/R way to set this up so the files are moved before installation?. Is there any git/git submodule way to set my repository up so that the files need not be copied?

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it is by moving the entire submodule to repo/pkg/src/submodule and then using .buildignore to ignore the files that I don't need.